# E/CrashlyticsCore: Failed to execute task getting errror

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I have implemented Crashlytics in app. I tried all answer given on stackoverflow.As suggested code is migrated to Androidx too.Still not able to resolved this.
Kindly check log for the error.
getting following error:

```
com.example.example E/CrashlyticsCore: Failed to execute task.
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:176)
   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.submitAndWait(CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.java:41)
    at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.handleUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:321)
    at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController$6.onUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:301)
    at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:42)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
08-09 16:53:53.056 26292-26292/com.example.example E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.example, PID: 26292
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.example/com.example.example.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: com.example.example.MainActivity() is not accessible from class android.app.Instrumentation
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2551)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: com.example.example.MainActivity() is not accessible from class android.app.Instrumentation
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1687)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2541)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
```

Project level Build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
    // Add dependency
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.0'  // Crashlytics plugin
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
} }
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()} }
```

App-level Build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.example"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
// (Recommended) Add Analytics
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.1'

// Add dependency
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
}
```

Can anyone help what I am missing.

Comment: add `ext.enableCrashlytics = true` in `buildTypes` debug/release section(build.gradle). Then restart IDE

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya tried but still getting the same error.

Comment: What file are you intializing crashlytics in? It looks like you are doing something in your instrumentation class that you should be doing in your main activity?
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.example/com.example.example.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: com.example.example.MainActivity() is not accessible from class android.app.Instrumentation

Comment: @ToddBurner  not initializing crashlytics manually.
As per document given on fire base console:
For Android apps, a hook in the AndroidManifest.xml file automatically initializes the Firebase SDK.

Comment: Are you using an emulator to test your app? Could you try using a physical device or a different emulator? I've seen this happen before on a particular emulator.

Comment: no running the app on Actual device.